# aspose word Dropdown list choose an item is not in SdtListItem

Tags: aspose.words

I have two dropdown list in word, both has an item with display name = “choose an item” and value = ‘’, as in attachment image,
but after fun following code

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
InputStream in;             
            in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/dropdown1.docx");
            Document doc = new Document(in);
            NodeCollection sdtNodes = doc.getChildNodes(NodeType.STRUCTURED_DOCUMENT_TAG, true);
            for (StructuredDocumentTag sdt : (Iterable<StructuredDocumentTag>)sdtNodes)
                if (sdt.getSdtType() == SdtType.DROP_DOWN_LIST)
                    for (SdtListItem item : (Iterable<SdtListItem>)sdt.getListItems()) {
                        System.out.println(item.getDisplayText() + " | " + item.getValue());
                    }
            doc.save(baOutputStream, SaveFormat.DOCX);
```

the output (as in code1)

1. only one dropdown list (dropdown1) has item.value = “| Choose an item.” (but not in item.getDisplayText()), another dropdown list (civilDept5_1) even has no item with value or displayText = “Choose an item”, why?
2. when I save the document and download the document, I find only one dropdown list (dropdown1) has the “choose an item” choice, another dropdown list (civilDept5) has lost this choice, why?

[image: dropdown1]
[image: civilDept5]
[image: code1]

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the dropdowns in your document is the following. In the first dropdown `"Choose an item."` items in the dropdown has value, but does not have displayed text:

```xml
<w:dropDownList>
    <w:listItem w:value="Choose an item."/>
    <w:listItem w:displayText="one" w:value="1"/>
    <w:listItem w:displayText="two" w:value="2"/>
</w:dropDownList>
```

In this case Aspose.Words preserves this item.
In the second dropdown, value of the `"Choose an item."` item is empty string and Aspose.Words skips this item:

```xml
<w:dropDownList>
    <w:listItem w:displayText="Choose an item." w:value=""/>
    <w:listItem w:displayText="Agriculture, Fisheries and Conservation Department" w:value="AFCD"/>
    <w:listItem w:displayText="Architectural Services Department" w:value="ARCHSD"/>
```

Dropdown controls also have placeholders, you can check `sdt.isShowingPlaceholderText()` and `sdt.getPlaceholder()` properties. For both dropdowns `sdt.getPlaceholder().toString(SaveFormat.TEXT)` returns `"Choose an item."`. This is the text you see when none of the items is selected.